# JRBeanCollectionDataSource in jasper how to use

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, jasper-reports, javabeans

```
try {
    //Connecting to the MySQL database

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital", "root" ,"root");

    String report="C:\\Users\\DELL\\report10.jrxml";

    JasperReport jasperreport=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
    patientDB DataBeanList = new patientDB();

    ArrayList<patientBean> dataList = DataBeanList.getDataBeanList();

    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource =
    new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList);
    Map<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    JasperPrint jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperreport, parameters,beanColDataSource);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    out.println(e);
}
```

i am new in jasper report trying to get value from bean class but nothing happen i spend my last 7 days for this

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify,

What is the error you are getting?

does the DataBeanList.getDataBeanList() return objects with values?

Is Db connection configuration is correct?

the path to jrxml is correct?(I think you don't need double slash in path)